# sleep command not found in torque pbs but works in shell

Tags: shell, pbs, torque

We create a torque pbs file "**testpbs**" as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -N T1272_flt
#PBS -q batch
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -o /data/software/torque-4.2.6.1/testpbs.sh.out
#PBS -e /data/software/torque-4.2.6.1/testpbs.sh.err  

sleep  20
```

Then submitted the file testbps.

> qsub testpbs

We got error messages:

> more testpbs.sh.err
>
> /var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/8.centos64.SC: line 9: sleep: command
>   not found

However, we ran **sleep 20** in command line. No error occurs.

> $sleep 20

Thanks in advance.

We ran **echo $PATH** in shell and got the following:

> echo $PATH
>
> /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/bin:/data/software/cufflinks-2.0.2.Linux_x86_64:/home/amin/bin/blast-2.2.19:/root/bin:/home/amin/bin

We use **qstat -f jobid** to review the details of this job.

> PBS_O_LOGNAME=amin,
>
> PBS_O_PATH= /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin: **/usr/local/sbin**: **/usr/local/bin**:
>   /sbin: **/bin**: /usr/sbin: **/usr/bin**: /sbin:/bin: /usr/sbin: /usr/bin:
>   /usr/X11R6/bin: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/bin:
>   /data/software/cufflinks-2.0.2.Linux_x86_64:
>   /home/amin/bin/blast-2.2.19: /root/bin: /home/aimin/bin,
>
> PBS_O_MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root,
>
> PBS_O_SHELL=/bin/bash,
>
> PBS_O_LANG=en_US.UTF-8,
>
> PBS_O_WORKDIR=/data/software/torque-4.2.6.1,
>
> PBS_O_HOST=centos64,
>
> PBS_O_SERVER=centos64

**Thank larsks's great help. The following works:**

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -N T1272_flt
#PBS -q batch
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -o /data/software/torque-4.2.6.1/testpbs.sh.out
#PBS -e /data/software/torque-4.2.6.1/testpbs.sh.err  

export PATH=$PBS_O_PATH
sleep  20
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing `sleep` with the full path to the command (possibly `/usr/bin/sleep`) and see if that changes the behavior.  If it does, then your script, when run under Torque, simply has a different (or empty) `$PATH` variable.

You can either (a) continue to use explicit paths, or (b) set `$PATH` explicitly in your script, e.g:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Thanks. we tried  **/bin/sleep 20** in pbs. It works. We tried **echo $PATH** in pbs. It displayed only **/home/amin/bin** . We use **qstat -f jobid** to review the details of this job. Please see the end part of my top post.