# GNUPlot cannot be executed after mpirun command in PBS script

Tags: mpi, pbs, torque

I have PBS command something like this

```
#PBS -N marcell_single_cell
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -l walltime=20000:00:00
#PBS -e stderr.log
#PBS -o stdout.log
# Specific the shell types
#PBS -S /bin/bash
# Specific the queue type
#PBS -q dque

#uncomment this if you want to debug the process
#set -vx

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

ulimit -s unlimited

NPROCS=`wc -l < $PBS_NODEFILE`

#export PATH=$PBS_O_PATH

echo This job has allocated $NPROCS nodes
echo Cleaning old files...
rm -rf *.png *.plt *.log
echo Cleaning success
/opt/Lib/openmpi-2.1.3/bin/mpirun -np $NPROCS  /scratch4/marcell/CellMLSimulator/bin/CellMLSimulator -ionmodel grandi2010 -solverType CVode  -irepeat 4 -dt 0.01
gnuplot -p plotting.gnu
```

It got error something like this, thrown by the PBS error log.

```
/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/6265.node01.SC: line 28: gnuplot: command not found
```

I've already make sure that the path of GNUPlot is already been added to the PATH environment variable.

However, the strange part is, if I interchange the sequence of command, like gnuplot first and then mpirun, there isn't any error. I suspect that some commands after mpirun need some special configs, but I dunno how to do that

Already following this solution, but no avail.

[sleep command not found in torque pbs but works in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248406/sleep-command-not-found-in-torque-pbs-but-works-in-shell)

EDITED:

it seems that the before and after mpirun still got error. and this is the which result:

```
which: no gnuplot in (/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/bin/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/bin/intel64:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/9.0-4/bin:/opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/prog/tools/grace/grace/bin:/home/prog/ansys_inc/v121/fluent/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/mpirt/bin/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/mpirt/bin/intel64:/scratch7/feber/jdk1.8.0_101:/scratch7/feber/code/apache-maven/bin:/usr/local/bin:/scratch7/cml/bin)
```

It's strange, since when I try to find the gnuplot, there is one in the /usr/local/bin

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/gnuplot 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3262113 Sep 18 2017 /usr/local/bin/gnuplot
```

moreover, if I run those commands without PBS, it seems executed as I expected:

```
/scratch4/marcell/CellMLSimulator/bin/CellMLSimulator -ionmodel grandi2010 -solverType CVode  -irepeat 4 -dt 0.01
gnuplot -p plotting.gnu
```

Comment: what if you `which gnuplot` before and after `mpirun` ?

Comment: ahh, I think it's also error. something like

which: no gnuplot in (/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/bin/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/bin/intel64:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/9.0-4/bin:/opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/prog/tools/grace/grace/bin:/home/prog/ansys_inc/v121/fluent/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/mpirt/bin/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/mpirt/bin/intel64:/scratch7/feber/jdk1.8.0_101:/scratch7/feber/code/apache-maven/bin:/usr/local/bin:/scratch7/cml/bin)

Comment: but when I tried to ls the dir at /usr/local/bin, the gnuplot command is there

ls -l /usr/local/bin/gnuplot

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3262113 Sep 18  2017 /usr/local/bin/gnuplot

Comment: is it before or after `mpirun` ? what if you explicitly run `/usr/local/bin/gnuplot` ? you might also want to `file /usr/local/bin/gnuplot` and `ldd /usr/local/bin/gnuplot` to check everything is there.

Comment: as a side note, logs are hardly readable when posted as comments, and you'd better edit your question.

Comment: yes, I just found the edit button. Thank you for your advice

Comment: Have you considered using `#PBS -V` in your script? From `man qsub`: _"Declares that all environment variables and shell functions in the user's login environment where qsub is run are to be exported to the job. The job's Variable_List attribute is appended with all of these environment variables and their values."_ This will also transfer your `PATH` to the job. That might help in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely that your system has different "login/head nodes" and "compute nodes". This is a commonly used practice in many supercomputing clusters. While you build and launch your application from the head node, it gets executed on one or more compute nodes.

The compute nodes can have different hardware and software compared to the head nodes. In your case, gnuplot is installed only on the head node, as you can see from the different outputs of `which gnuplot`. To solve this, you have three approaches:

1. Request the system administrators to install gnuplot on the compute nodes.
2. Build and install your own version of gnuplot in a file-system accessible from the compute nodes. It could be your home directory or somewhere else depending on your cluster. In general, the filesystem where your application is will be available. In your case, anywhere under `/scratch4/marcell/` would probably work.
3. Run gnuplot on the head node after the MPI jobs finish as a post-processing step. PBS/Torque does not provide a direct way to do this. You'll need to write a separate bash (not PBS) script to do this.

Comment: ahh I see. I understand what you mean. So it means I need to add gnuplot to compute nodes? 

and I intrigued for the number 3. so let's say my PBS script named simulator.sh, my plotting is plotting.gnu. Is there any method how to run the PBS and non-PBS script consecutively without waiting the PBS scheduler stopped? Since I cannot be allowed to install gnuplot to each compute nodes separately.